# How to show only part of icon in imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-icons

I'm facing some problem with imageview of Android, i have a small icon but the image is very big, if i give wrap_content to image view, the icon looks small but the view looks too big,

Have look at the below image

[image]

Because of the icon, Time and Count text looks too small and the rest of the view looks blank. i.e on top & bottom, you can see the blue color border which i have selected has got so much of empty space.

Here is my imageview code,

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ID_Call_Type_Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_incoming_call"
            android:text="Time"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

So, to display the icon just at the level of Time/Count Text font what i have to do?. i googled but no luck :(

Comment: sorry, what's the expected result? If the icon itself has a white space, I don't think you can do something about it other than fixing the icon.

Comment: Yes, you are right, ho wmuch would be the specified size of icon for HDPI, XHDPI, MDPI & XXHDPI icon resolutions

Comment: see Image scaling: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-designing-layouts-for-dp . You also can try to 'hack' your icon via negative margins. In some cases it is possible to put other views on top of the image so that it looks nice.. But fixing the icon would be better, of course